# Javascript creating an HTML object vs creating an HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty simple question that I couldn't find an answer to, maybe because it's a non-issue, but I'm wondering if there is a difference between creating an HTML object using Javascript or using a string to build an element.  Like, is it a better practice to declare any HTML elements in JS as JS objects or as strings and let the browser/library/etc parse them?  For example:

```
jQuery('<div />', {'class': 'example'});
```

vs

```
jQuery('<div class="example></div>');
```

(Just using jQuery as an example, but same question applies for vanilla JS as well.)

It seems like a non-issue to me but I'm no JS expert, and I want to make sure I'm doing it right.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're both "correct".  And both are useful at different times for different purposes.

For instance, in terms of page-speed, these days it's faster to just do something like:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<header>....big string o' html text</footer>";
```

The browser will spit it out in an instant.

As a matter of safety, when dealing with user-input, it's safer to build elements, attach them to a `documentFragment` and then append them to the DOM (or replace a DOM node with your new version, or whatever).

Consider:

```
var userPost = "My name is Bob.<script src=\"//bad-place.com/awful-things.js\"></script>",
    paragraph = "<p>" + userPost + "</p>";

commentList.innerHTML += paragraph;
```

Versus:

```
var userPost = "My name is Bob.<script src=\"//bad-place.com/awful-things.js\"></script>",
    paragraph = document.createElement("p");

    paragraph.appendChild( document.createTextNode(userPost) );
    commentList.appendChild(paragraph);
```

One does bad things and one doesn't.

Of course, you don't have to create `textNodes`, you could use `innerText` or `textContent` or whatever (the browser will create the text node on its own).

But it's always important to consider what you're sharing and how.

If it's coming from anywhere other than a place you trust (which should be approximately nowhere, unless you're serving static pages, in which case, why are you building html?), then you should keep injection in mind -- only the things you WANT to be injected should be.

Comment: Thanks for the response(s) everyone.  This one illustrates the difference most clearly, for me anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Either can be preferable depending on your particular scenario—ie, if everything is hard-coded, option 2 is probably better, as @camus said.

One limitation with the first option though, is that this

```
$("<div data-foo='X' />", { 'class': 'example' });
```

will *not* work.  That overload expects a naked tag as the first parameter with no attributes at all.

This was reported [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11698)

Answer (score 0):

1/ is better if your attribubes depends on variables set before calling the $ function , dont have to concatenate strings and variables. Aside from that fact ,since you can do both , and it's just some js code somebody else wrote , not a C++ DOM API hardcoded in the browser...